# Selenium connection

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get a webpage with `Selenium` with this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

IEdriver= 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'
browser = webdriver.Ie(IEdriver)
browser.get('www.google.com')
```

When `IE` is open, it tries to connect to :

```
http://--port=60803/
```

And I can't connect to Google. Does anyone know why ?

EDIT:

The exception is :

```
WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Se
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
ervice C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add scheme (application layer protocol you want to use) to `URL`, so replace

```
browser.get('www.google.com')
```

with

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Also there is another problem in your code:

`IEdriver= 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'` points on `IE` browser binary file while `webdriver.Ie()` should get path to `IEDriverServer.exe` as value for `executable_path` parameter

Comment: It doen't work neither, the same error but with another port number

Comment: Show exact exception log you get when using `browser.get('https://www.google.com')`

Comment: I added some infor regarding the error that I get after IE opens and get nothing

Comment: Check updated answer and replace `IEdriver= 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'` with something like `IEdriver= 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEDriverServer.exe'`